# Selector :not in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a body with ID `body` and inside it a div with class `nav-container`. I want to remove certain classes when users click on the `#body`, but not `.nav-container` (it's an overlay type of menu).

Tried below code

HTML:

```
<body id="body">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <a href="#" id="close-btn"> X </a>
    <nav class="display">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> One </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Two </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Three </a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
 </div>
</body>
```

jQuery

```
$('#body :not(.nav-container)').click(function() {
    $('.cover').removeClass('active-cover');
    $('.nav-container').removeClass('active');
});
```

It does not seem to be working for me though.

Comment: that would bind click events to every tag under body but one, surely you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It wont work as `not` exclude the selected elements which pass the earlier css-selector criteria since `.nav-container` is not part of list that is selected by `#body` (wont be list in this case as its ID), so you wont be able to exclude that.
So basically what you need is

```
$(document).on("click", "div:not('.nav-container')",function() {
    $('.cover').removeClass('active-cover');
    $('.nav-container').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: updated the answer, it would be more clear If you explain whats your exact requirement

Answer (score 0):

the first element shouldn't be the parent, like #body, rather the element. for example `div:not('example')` works for every div except example.

```js
$("div:not(.nav-container)").click(function() {
alert("nav-container was not clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="body">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <a href="#" id="close-btn"> X </a>
    <nav class="display">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> One </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Two </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Three </a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
 </div>
  <br />
  <div>click here </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Niralana it is working like that if you test the snippet. are you sure the class names are correct?

Comment: the snippet provided displays the same alert wherever you click